# how to use hadoop deal with cross-data input file tasks?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

> Using HADOOP to deal with some data like log files is very useful.
>   Because, in theory, we can split the data file to some block, and each
>   node can process this separate block to generate k-v pairs which
>   are then passed to a mapper and reducer. But if our task's input data file is
>   more complicate , meaning we not split or every compute node but need the
>   whole input data , how do we do that?
>
> for example
>
> We want to calculate every two vector's distance. In the input file
>   each line implies a vector. This problem definitely can be a parallel
>   process since every node can compute the distance of one vector
>   and all other vectors. But how do we use use HADOOP framework to deal with
>   this? In other words, how to split this input data file to some block so
>   that we can produce some key-value from each block, and then pass
>   them to mapper and reducer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle graph data in Hadoop take a look at [Apache Giraph](http://giraph.apache.org/) or [titan](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Using-HBase) (built on HBase)